# Circular Buffers embedded C but with Dynamic Struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, buffer, circular-dependency

I don't really understand pointers, find them so difficult to understand its unreal. I don't think I will ever ever grasp POINTERs when sending to functions *   & omg ...

I am using arm nucleo board to transfer CAN data

I have created a Struct for CAN Bus 1 & Can Bus 2 data which takes care of the CAN incoming messages

1. CAN type of packet
2. CAN HEADER ID
3. CAN DATA

```
typedef struct can_packet_s
    {
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_Message_Type;                            
        uint32_t            RX_CAN_ID;                                      
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_DATA[8];                                         
    }can_packet_t;
```

once the interrupt executes for incoming CAN data I store it in the above struct variables

but I want to go one stage further I want to add this data to a circular buffer

I have a circular buffer buffer working, I don't really understand how it all works with all the * / pointers calling various functions, its a total maze of trying to under stand?

but this circular buffer only works with a variable when initialized?

How can I get rid of the variable and transpose it to the struct? I basically want to have a dynamic struct of can data not a single variable.

here is the circular buffer (though if some one can explain)

The *data I want to get rid of and replace with my dynamic can struct of how ever deep I want to make the fifo, how can this be done. I have spent days trying?

fifo.h

```
#pragma once
 
// types
typedef struct fifo_buffer_s
{
    uint16_t *data;                 // pointer to external buffer
    uint16_t  size;                 // size of external buffer
    uint16_t  head;                 // index of free space in external buffer
    uint16_t  tail;                 // index of last item to be read
    uint16_t  count;                // hold number of items stored but not read
} fifo_buffer_t;
 
// interface
void      FIFO_Init   (fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint16_t* in_buffer, uint16_t buffer_size_in_bytes);
void      FIFO_Reset  (fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state);                                               // note: does not clear external buffer
uint8_t   FIFO_IsEmpty(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state);                                               // return non-zero if buffer is empty
uint8_t   FIFO_IsFull (fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state);                                               // return non-zero if buffer is full
uint8_t   FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint16_t  new_item);                           // return non-zero if buffer is full
uint8_t   FIFO_GetItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint16_t* const out_item);                     // return non-zero if buffer is empty
```

fifo.c

```
#include "main.h"


// Simple prove-of-concept fifo buffer
// Author: Adam Orcholski, www.tath.eu
 
// #include <fifobuffer.h>
#include <assert.h>
 
// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO INIT ROUTINE ASSIGNS NEW DATA TO STRUCTURE   ***********
// ************************************************************************     

void FIFO_Init(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint16_t* in_buffer, uint16_t buffer_size_in_bytes)
{
    assert(0 != buff_state);
    assert(0 != in_buffer);
    assert(buffer_size_in_bytes > 0);
 
    buff_state->data = in_buffer;
    buff_state->size = buffer_size_in_bytes;
    buff_state->head =  0;
    buff_state->tail =  0;
    buff_state->count = 0;
}
 
// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO RESET ROUTINE RESETS DATA IN STRUCTURE to 0   **********
// ************************************************************************ 

void FIFO_Reset(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{
    assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    buff_state->head = 0;
    buff_state->tail = 0;
    buff_state->count = 0;
}

// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO RESET ROUTINE RESETS DATA IN STRUCTURE to 0   **********
// ************************************************************************ 
 
// return non-zero value if buffer is empty
uint8_t FIFO_IsEmpty(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsEmpty = 0;
 
    assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    if (0 == buff_state->count)
    {
        fBufferIsEmpty = 1;
    }
 
    return fBufferIsEmpty;
}

// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO RESET ROUTINE RESETS DATA IN STRUCTURE to 0   **********
// ************************************************************************ 
 
// return non-zero value if buffer is full
uint8_t FIFO_IsFull(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsFull = 0;
 
    assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    if (buff_state->count >= (buff_state->size / sizeof(buff_state->size)))
    {
        fBufferIsFull = 1;
    }
 
    return fBufferIsFull;
}

// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO ADD ITEM ROUTINE Returns Non 0 If FIFO Full  ***********
// ************************************************************************ 

// return non-zero value if buffer is full
uint8_t  FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint16_t new_item)
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsFull = 0;
 
    assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    fBufferIsFull = FIFO_IsFull(buff_state);
 
    if (!fBufferIsFull)
    {
        buff_state->data[buff_state->head] = new_item;
        buff_state->head++;
        buff_state->count++;
 
        if (buff_state->head >= (buff_state->size / sizeof(buff_state->size)))
        {
            buff_state->head = 0;
        }
    }
 
 
    return fBufferIsFull;
}
 
// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO GET ITEM ROUTINE Returns Non 0 If FIFO Empty  **********
// ************************************************************************ 

// return non-zero value if buffer is empty
uint8_t  FIFO_GetItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint16_t* const out_item)
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsEmpty = 0;
 
    assert(0 != buff_state);
    assert(0 != out_item);
 
    fBufferIsEmpty = FIFO_IsEmpty(buff_state);
 
    if (!fBufferIsEmpty)
    {
        *out_item = buff_state->data[buff_state->tail];
        buff_state->tail++;
        buff_state->count--;
 
        if (buff_state->tail >= (buff_state->size / sizeof(buff_state->size)))
        {
            buff_state->tail = 0;
        }
    }
 
    return fBufferIsEmpty;
}
```

To set it up in main.c

```
// - CAN RX FIFO Data Handle Structure FiFo Variables -

  #define         CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 32                                                                // define can rx message fifo buffer to 32 byte fifo
  uint16_t        can_rx_fifo_buffer[CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE];                                              // create BUFFER ARRAY for can_rx_fifo with above size
 
  fifo_buffer_t   can_rx_fifo;   


 FIFO_Init( &can_rx_fifo   , can_rx_fifo_buffer    , sizeof(can_rx_fifo_buffer  ));                   // INIT FIFO FOR CAN INCOMING MESSAGES
```

then to add data

```
  ret = FIFO_AddItem( &can_rx_fifo, RxHeader.StdId    );
```

but this is no good for what I want, this fifo simply uses one 16bit variable with a depth of sizeof(can_rx_fifo_buffer  )

how can I replace the *data with my CAN struct

```
{
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_Message_Type;                            
        uint32_t            RX_CAN_ID;                                      
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_DATA[8];                                         
    }can_packet_t;
```

so the depth of this fifo is multiple structs in memory

this code below inits the fifo and I think makes the fifo struct element *data which is 16bits wide a type of array? pointer array? by can_rx_fifo_buffer[CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE]

FIFO_Init( &can_rx_fifo   , can_rx_fifo_buffer    , sizeof(can_rx_fifo_buffer  ));

I know what I want to do, how ones does it even if it can be done I have not a clue?

simply want to modify this working circular fifo code to create multiple CAN structs in memory and I set how deep the fifo struct are

1. so we must first start by creating the struct which is already done...

```
typedef struct can_packet_s
    {
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_Message_Type;                            
        uint32_t            RX_CAN_ID;                                      
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_DATA[8];                                         
                            // could always add more variables here ?
   }can_packet_t;
```

2. we can now workout the size of the struct with all its elements

```
int size=0;
size = sizeof(can_packet_t);
```

ok so we now know the size of memory to store one complete CAN struct in memory

3. I now need to allocate a section of memory to store the desired number of strucs in my fifo

how do I do this?

is something like this

fifo.h

```
// types
typedef struct fifo_buffer_s
{
    // uint16_t *data;                 // get rid of INT 16 data pointer to external buffer
  
// now add the struct to replace variable data ?
// do i make this a pointer struct ??? don't understand pointer to struct or varaibles ????


 struct can_pack_s
    {
        uint8_t             *RX_CAN_Message_Type;                           
        uint32_t            *RX_CAN_ID;                                     
        uint8_t             *RX_CAN_DATA[8];                                            
                            // could always add more variables here?
   }*can_pack_t;
                           // possibly right? haven't a clue?


    uint16_t  size;                 // size of external buffer
    uint16_t  head;                 // index of free space in external buffer
    uint16_t  tail;                 // index of last item to be read
    uint16_t  count;                // hold number of items stored but not read
} fifo_buffer_t;
```

Then I can send use

uint8_t   FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint16_t  new_item);

but not send a 16bit variable new_item I want to send my CAN struct and write all elements to my fifo struct?

please reply and hemp in very basic terms, I want to understand how to do this, I think I'm on the right course, but need very basic stage by stage answers

thank you in advance

---

Thank you very much for your input and help, I spent yesterday rewriting the code from top to bottom, at each stage trying to fully understand what is going on and proving each stage.

I'm not quite there but making head way, the problem I have is making the CAN Strut in to an array and accessing it

```
/******************************************************************************

Welcome to GDB Online.
GDB online is an online compiler and debugger tool for C, C++, Python, Java, PHP, Ruby, Perl,
C#, OCaml, VB, Swift, Pascal, Fortran, Haskell, Objective-C, Assembly, HTML, CSS, JS, SQLite, Prolog.
Code, Compile, Run and Debug online from anywhere in world.

*******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>



// create can structure used multiple times



typedef struct can_pack     // <--- type define struct saves mentioning struct every time a new struct is created
{
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_Message_Type;    // used to store can message type                            
        uint32_t            RX_CAN_ID;              // used to store can ID / std or ext
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_DATA[8];         // used to store 8bytes of can data
        
}   can_pack_t;             // <--- name of CAN Packet structure


// create fifo buffer structure used once for each fifo creation
typedef struct fifo_buff    // <--- type define struct saves mentioning struct every time a new struct is created
{
        uint16_t  can_packet_size;      // size of total can packet structure
        uint16_t  can_packet_size_fifo; // size of total can packet fifo structure
        uint8_t   fifo_depth_size;      // depth of fifo
        uint16_t  head;                 // index of free space in external buffer
        uint16_t  tail;                 // index of last item to be read
        uint16_t  count;                // hold number of items stored but not read
}   fifo_buffer_t;




// create CAN_RX Structure & CAN_Fifo Structure In Memory

#define fifo_deep  10                           // fifo buffer 10 deep
can_pack_t      can_struct_fifo[fifo_deep];    // can fifo 10bytes deep (allocates can struct in memory 10bytes)
can_pack_t      can_rx;                        // used in can interrupt to get data can packet

fifo_buffer_t   can_fifo;                      // create instance of Fifo Buffer 





// decalre fifo prototypes                                         

void FIFO_Init(fifo_buffer_t * const, uint8_t , uint16_t  );            // FIFO_Init prototype decloration
void FIFO_Reset(fifo_buffer_t * const);                                 // FIFO_Reset prototype decloration              
uint8_t FIFO_IsEmpty(fifo_buffer_t * const );                           // FIFO_IsEmpty prototype decloration              
uint8_t FIFO_IsFull(fifo_buffer_t * const b);                           // FIFO_IsFull prototype decloration              
uint8_t FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const , can_pack_t * const[], can_pack_t * const);


uint8_t ret;                                                            // return variable


int main()
{

 printf("size of can_rx stucture =   %d\n", (int)sizeof(can_rx));
 printf("size of can_fifo stucture = %d\n", (int)sizeof(can_struct_fifo));
// printf("size of can_fifo stucture = %d\n", (int)sizeof(can_fifo));




                                                // pass structure can_fifo (pointer) start address to function FiFo_init
                                                // allows eliments of can_fifo to be modified in function FiFo_Init
                                                // pass size of can_rx_struc & pass size of can_struct_fifo
                                                // call fifo init
FIFO_Init( &can_fifo,   (uint8_t)sizeof(can_rx), (uint16_t)sizeof(can_struct_fifo)) ;                 

// *** call & test fifo_Reset routine ***

FIFO_Reset( &can_fifo);


// *** call & test fifo_IsEmpty routine ***
ret = FIFO_IsEmpty( &can_fifo);

if (ret==0)
        {
        printf("\nbuffer has data %d) ",ret); 
        }
        
else    {
        printf("\nbuffer is empty %d) ",ret);
        }    
        
// *** call & test fifo_IsFull routine ***        
 ret = FIFO_IsFull( &can_fifo);       
        
if (ret==0)
        {
        printf("\nbuffer not full %d) ",ret); 
        }
        
else    {
        printf("\nbuffer is full %d) ",ret);
        }           
        
        
                                        // *** call & test fifo_AddItem routine ***
                                        // 1) pass pointer to can_fifo
                                        // 2) pass pointer to can_Struct_fifo
                                        // 2) pass pointer to can_interrupt read data
 ret = FIFO_AddItem( &can_fifo  , &can_struct_fifo , &can_rx );
        
        
        
        
    return 0;
}


// ************************************************************************
// ****** FIFO INIT ROUTINE INITIALISES NEW STRUCTURE VALUES IN FIFO  *****
// ************************************************************************ 
                                                    // buffer init routine
                                                    // 1) pass struct fifo buffer pointer
                                                    // 2) pass size of can_rx structure  (one can packet)
                                                    // 3) pass size of can_fifo_stucture (declated # can packet fifo size)
void FIFO_Init(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint8_t can_struct_size,  uint16_t can_struct_fifo_size)
{
    // assert(0 != buff_state);
    buff_state->can_packet_size         = can_struct_size;      // store passed (can_struct_size) in fifo struct member (buff_state->can_packet_size)
    buff_state->can_packet_size_fifo    = can_struct_fifo_size; // store passed (can_struct_fifo_size) in fifo struct member (buff_state->can_packet_size_fifo)
    buff_state->head                    = 5;                    // store 0 in buff_state->head
    buff_state->tail                    = 6;                    // store 0 in buff_state->tail
    buff_state->count                   = 9;                    // store 0 in buff_state->count
                                                                // calculate fifo buffer depth from passed data
                                                                // store buffer depth in buff_state->fifo_depth_size  
    buff_state->fifo_depth_size         = buff_state->can_packet_size_fifo / buff_state->can_packet_size;
                                                                // print fifo truct member values just to confirm everything is correct.
    
    printf("\ncan_struct_size       = %d",buff_state->can_packet_size);
    printf("\ncan_fifo_struct_size  = %d",buff_state->can_packet_size_fifo);
    printf("\ncan_fifo_depth        = %d",buff_state->fifo_depth_size);
    printf("\nfifo head             = %d",buff_state->head);
    printf("\nfifo tail             = %d",buff_state->tail);
    printf("\nfifo count            = %d",buff_state->count);
    printf("\n\nfifo above variables Initialised");
}


// ************************************************************************
// ********* FIFO RESET ROUTINE RESETS & CLEARS DATA IN STRUCTURE *********
// ************************************************************************ 
                                                    // buffer reset routine
                                                    // 1) pass struct fifo buffer pointer to allow reset of fifo struct members

void FIFO_Reset(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{
    // assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    buff_state->head  = 0;                                  // store 0 in buff_state->head
    buff_state->tail  = 0;                                  // store 0 in buff_state->tail
    buff_state->count = 0;                                  // store 0 in buff_state->count
                                                            // print fifo truct member values just to confirm everything is correct.
                                                            
    printf("\nfifo head             = %d",buff_state->head);
    printf("\nfifo tail             = %d",buff_state->tail);
    printf("\nfifo count            = %d",buff_state->count);
    printf("\n\nfifo above variables Reset");
    
}


// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO IsEmpty ROUTINE RETURNS 1 FOR EMPTY & 0 FOR FULL********
// ************************************************************************ 
 
// return non-zero value if buffer is empty
                                                    // is fifo empty routine
                                                    // 1) pass struct fifo buffer pointer to allow read of fifo struct members

uint8_t FIFO_IsEmpty(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsEmpty = 0;                     // init fBufferIsEmpty to 0
                                                    // buffer has data condition (0) COUNT >0
 
    //assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    if (0 == buff_state->count)                     // IF 0 = count value (fifo member count)
    {
        fBufferIsEmpty = 1;                         // return 1 (buffer is empty)
    }
 
    return fBufferIsEmpty;                          // return variable fBufferIsEmpty
}



// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO RESET ROUTINE RESETS DATA IN STRUCTURE to 0   **********
// ************************************************************************ 
 
// return non-zero value if buffer is full
uint8_t FIFO_IsFull(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{                                                   // is fifo full routine
                                                    // 1) pass struct fifo buffer pointer to allow read of fifo struct members
    uint8_t fBufferIsFull = 0;                      // set buffer not full
 
   // assert(0 != buff_state);
                                                    // if count is greater or equal to fifo_depth_size
    if (buff_state->count >= buff_state->fifo_depth_size)
    {
        fBufferIsFull = 1;                          // set buffer full flag
    }
 
    return fBufferIsFull;                           // return variable fBufferIsFull
}




// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO ADD ITEM ROUTINE Returns Non 0 If FIFO Full  ***********
// ************************************************************************ 

// return non-zero value if buffer is full
uint8_t  FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, can_pack_t * const can_fifo[buff_state->fifo_depth_size] , can_pack_t * const can_pac )
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsFull = 0;                  // set buffer full to 0
 
  //  assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    fBufferIsFull = FIFO_IsFull(buff_state);    // call FIFO_IsFull Routine, returns 1 if full
 
    if (!fBufferIsFull)                         // if buffer not full proceed below
    {
        //buff_state->data[buff_state->head] = new_item;
        //buff_state->[buff_state->head] = new_item;
        
        can_fifo[buff_state->head]->RX_CAN_Message_Type = can_pac->RX_CAN_Message_Type;
        can_fifo[buff_state->head]->RX_CAN_ID           = can_pac->RX_CAN_ID;
        memcpy (can_fifo[buff_state->head]->RX_CAN_DATA, can_pac->RX_CAN_DATA, 8 );
        
        buff_state->head++;
        buff_state->count++;
 
        if (buff_state->head >= buff_state->fifo_depth_size)
        {
            buff_state->head = 0;
        }
  
    printf("\ncan fifo[%d] Message Value = %d",buff_state->head, can_fifo[buff_state->head]->RX_CAN_Message_Type);

  
  
    }
 
 
 
 
    return fBufferIsFull;
}
```

please ignore my over the top comments and printf, I am just trying to understand each stage

when creating the can fifo struct as below

```
#define fifo_deep  10                           // fifo buffer 10 deep
can_pack_t      can_struct_fifo[fifo_deep];
```

this is the part that creates how deep the struct is in the fifo buffo

but not sure how to pass this to a function ??

I did almost have it working last night as below on my dev system, segger jlink and visual GDB

I was able to write two complete structs sequentially to memory but then the third can packet jumped many many bytes of memory

I know the problem is tied up with the Struct array and referencing correctly

```
// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO ADD ITEM ROUTINE Returns Non 0 If FIFO Full  ***********
// ************************************************************************ 

// return non-zero value if buffer is full
uint8_t  FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, can_pack_t can_fifo[] , can_pack_t * const can_pac )
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsFull = 0;                  // set buffer full to 0

  //  assert(0 != buff_state);

    fBufferIsFull = FIFO_IsFull(buff_state);    // call FIFO_IsFull Routine, returns 1 if full

    if (!fBufferIsFull)                         // if buffer not full proceed below
    {
        //buff_state->data[buff_state->head] = new_item;
        //buff_state->[buff_state->head] = new_item;

        can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_Message_Type = can_pac->RX_CAN_Message_Type;
        can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_ID           = can_pac->RX_CAN_ID;
        memcpy (can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_DATA,  can_pac->RX_CAN_DATA, 8 );

        buff_state->head++;
        buff_state->count++;

        if (buff_state->head >= buff_state->fifo_depth_size)
        {
            buff_state->head = 0;
        }

    printf("\ncan fifo[%d] Message Value = %d",buff_state->head,   can_fifo[buff_state->head]->RX_CAN_Message_Type);



    }




    return fBufferIsFull;
}
```

any help with this part will be much appreciated

Regards

John

Answer (score 1):

Two salient points in your question.

"Want to store 'n' buffers." You've made a valiant effort with a "circular buffer" using an array. Sadly, without far more complex code, you may encounter "buffer full" conditions and be unable to store important data.
This may be unavoidable in an `embedded` system. Dynamic memory allocation is usually forbidden in that space.

"Step by step". There is lots of information available. Find a source that makes sense to you.

I've taken snippets of your code and stripped them down to a reasonable minimum in the hope that you can follow what is happening. It's best to NOT try to write code without understanding what it is supposed to do. You wind up with a 'blob' and can't begin to diagnose misbehaviours. Work incrementally and make 'checkpoint' copies of files that have be tested and shown to work.

Good luck!

```
// Your basic "message" block
typedef struct {
    uint8_t     RX_CAN_Message_Type;
    uint32_t    RX_CAN_ID;
    uint8_t     RX_CAN_DATA[8];
                // Yes! can add more variables here!
} can_packet_t;

// Temporarily reduce the size for this example
//#define   CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 32
#define CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 3

// An array to hold upto 'n' "messages" compiled into the wrapping structure
typedef struct {
    can_packet_t data[ CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE ];
    uint16_t head;      // index of next spot to write
    uint16_t tail;      // index of next spot to read
    uint16_t count;     // number of items stored
} fifo_buffer_t;


// unnecessary duplication of "reset()"
// void      FIFO_Init(); 


// Simply zero-out the FIFO buffer
void FIFO_Reset( fifo_buffer_t *p ) {

    // Check, as far as can be done, address is not bad
    // Omitted check in other example functions for brevity
    if( p == NULL )
        exit( 1 );

    memset( p, 0, sizeof *p );
}


// fairly obvious
bool FIFO_IsEmpty( fifo_buffer_t *p ) {
    return p->count == 0;
}

// and obvious here, too
bool FIFO_IsFull( fifo_buffer_t *p ) {
    return p->count == CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE;
}


// adapted your code to serve 'struct' instead of 'int'
bool FIFO_AddItem( fifo_buffer_t *p, can_packet_t *item ) {
    bool isFull = FIFO_IsFull( p );

    if( !isFull ) {
        memcpy( &p->data[ p->head ], item, sizeof p->data[0] );
        p->count++;
        p->head++;
        if( p->head >= CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE ) // wrap around
            p->head = 0;
    }

    return isFull;
}

// Same, but now "read" instead of "write" the item
bool FIFO_GetItem( fifo_buffer_t *p, can_packet_t *item ) {
    // functions receive address(es) and use those as pointers
    bool isEmpty = FIFO_IsEmpty( p);

    if( !isEmpty ) {
        memcpy( item, &p->data[ p->tail ], sizeof *item );
        p->count--;
        p->tail++;
        if( p->tail >= CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE )
            p->tail = 0;
    }
 
    return isEmpty;
}


int main() {
    fifo_buffer_t can_rx_fifo; // One instance, local to main()

    FIFO_Reset( &can_rx_fifo );

    // simulating 4 distinct packets to be saved in FIFO order
    can_packet_t  packs[] = {
        { 27, 100000003, 32, 32, 32 }, 
        { 27, 100000004, 32, 32, 32 }, 
        { 27, 100000005, 32, 32, 32 }, 
        { 27, 100000006, 32, 32, 32 }, 
    };

    // Attempt to save 4 packets when only room for 3 max...
    // main() passes the addresses of structs to the functions
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof packs/sizeof packs[0]; i++ ) {
        bool rVal = FIFO_AddItem( &can_rx_fifo, &packs[ i ] );

        printf( "#%d - %s\n", i, rVal ? "Failure" : "Success" );
    }


    can_packet_t item; // location to retrieve packet if available
    while( FIFO_GetItem( &can_rx_fifo, &item ) != true ) { // Strange, but as per description
        printf( "%d\n", item.RX_CAN_ID );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks good.   I would swap-out the `NULL` check-and-exit in `FIFO_Reset()` with an `assert( p != NULL )`, so at least this can be caught in a debugger, but takes no space in release code.  If it's worth checking at this one place, it should also be checked in the other FIFO functions.

Comment: @Kingsley It's primitive, but I hope OP poster can follow how '&' and '*' are being used in this simplified version. Re `assert()`:  Rule #1 - NEVER trust received pointers... I wrote one instance as an example, omitting duplications for brevity. Soft or Hard response is up to the application requirements, of course. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's really not easy to understand pointers, but you don't need a book for that. Understand the pointer as a variable type that contains some memory address. Let's see an example:

```
int num = 10;
int *pointer = &num; // & returns with the address of the num variable
printf("Memory address of num:%p\n", pointer); // output: the memory address of the data
printf("The data stored at the memory address:%d\n", *pointer); // output: the stored variable, 10
```

I hope this short code can help you, but you should try it yourself, practice it.
Let's see your questions:

1. "How can I get rid of the variable and transpose it to the struct?"
   A: Simple, you should ovewrite it with your struct.

   typedef struct fifo_buffer_s
   {
   can_pack_t* data;
   uint16_t  size;
   uint16_t  head;
   uint16_t  tail;
   uint16_t  count;
   } fifo_buffer_t;
2. "*data wich is 16bits wide a type of array? pointer array? by can_rx_fifo_buffer[CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE]"
   A: *data is a memory address, a pointer type of variable. It stores a memory address. When you init the fifo structure, you give the start of memory address of your array.

Your fifo implementation is ok, but it is not circular buffer. If buffer is full and you get a new data, then you have to overwrite the first data received with it.

- you replace uint16_t with can_pack_t like this: uint8_t  FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, can_pack_t new_item)

Your array will be:

```
#define         CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE 32                                                           
can_pack_t can_rx_fifo_buffer[CAN_RX_BUFFER_SIZE];                   
fifo_buffer_t    can_rx_fifo;
```

Good luck with trying to code this!

Comment: Why did chris delete my last post ??? I was after some help please don not delete posts chris, many thanks to everyone else for helping me

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I have done it

```
*******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>


// create can structure used multiple times



typedef struct can_pack     // <--- type define struct saves mentioning struct every time a new struct is created
{
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_Message_Type;    // used to store can message type                            
        uint32_t            RX_CAN_ID;              // used to store can ID / std or ext
        uint8_t             RX_CAN_DATA[8];         // used to store 8bytes of can data
        
}   can_pack_t;             // <--- name of CAN Packet structure


// create fifo buffer structure used once for each fifo creation
typedef struct fifo_buff    // <--- type define struct saves mentioning struct every time a new struct is created
{
        uint16_t  can_packet_size;      // size of total can packet structure
        uint16_t  can_packet_size_fifo; // size of total can packet fifo structure
        uint8_t   fifo_depth_size;      // depth of fifo
        uint16_t  head;                 // index of free space in external buffer
        uint16_t  tail;                 // index of last item to be read
        uint16_t  count;                // hold number of items stored but not read
}   fifo_buffer_t;




// create CAN_RX Structure & CAN_Fifo Structure In Memory

#define fifo_deep  10                           // fifo buffer 5 deep
can_pack_t      can_struct_fifo[fifo_deep];    // can fifo 10bytes deep (allocates can struct in memory 10bytes)
can_pack_t      can_rx;                        // used in can interrupt to get data can packet

fifo_buffer_t   can_fifo;                      // create instance of Fifo Buffer 





// decalre fifo prototypes                                         

void FIFO_Init(fifo_buffer_t * const, uint8_t , uint16_t  );            // FIFO_Init prototype decloration
void FIFO_Reset(fifo_buffer_t * const);                                 // FIFO_Reset prototype decloration              
uint8_t FIFO_IsEmpty(fifo_buffer_t * const );                           // FIFO_IsEmpty prototype decloration              
uint8_t FIFO_IsFull(fifo_buffer_t * const b);                           // FIFO_IsFull prototype decloration              
uint8_t FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const , can_pack_t * , can_pack_t * const );


uint8_t ret;                                                            // return variable
uint8_t i,a,b;

int main()
{

 printf("size of can_rx   stucture = %d bytes\n", (int)sizeof(can_rx));
 printf("size of can_fifo stucture = %d bytes\n", (int)sizeof(can_struct_fifo));
// printf("size of can_fifo stucture = %d\n", (int)sizeof(can_fifo));




                                                // pass structure can_fifo (pointer) start address to function FiFo_init
                                                // allows eliments of can_fifo to be modified in function FiFo_Init
                                                // pass size of can_rx_struc & pass size of can_struct_fifo
                                                // call fifo init
FIFO_Init( &can_fifo,   (uint8_t)sizeof(can_rx), (uint16_t)sizeof(can_struct_fifo)) ;                 

// *** call & test fifo_Reset routine ***

FIFO_Reset( &can_fifo);


// *** call & test fifo_IsEmpty routine ***
ret = FIFO_IsEmpty( &can_fifo);

printf("\n\n*****************************************");  

if (ret==0)
        {
        printf("\nbuffer has data %d) ",ret); 
        }
        
else    {
        printf("\nbuffer has no data (empty) %d) ",ret);
        }    
 
 
printf("\n\nResult from Function FIFI_IsEmpty");
printf("\n*****************************************");
        
// *** call & test fifo_IsFull routine ***        
 ret = FIFO_IsFull( &can_fifo);                     // send pointer of can_fifo
 
printf("\n\n*****************************************");          
if (ret==0)
        {
        printf("\nbuffer is not full %d) ",ret); 
        }
        
else    {
        printf("\nbuffer is full %d) ",ret);
        }           
 printf("\n\nResult from Function FIFI_IsFull");  
 printf("\n*****************************************");  
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
   
// *** call & test fifo_AddItem routine ***   
   
// lets first write some data in to the Can RX Strut, this will then get copied across to the Can Fifo Struct once FIFO_AddItem item is called
   
   can_rx.RX_CAN_Message_Type =6; 
   can_rx.RX_CAN_ID=7;
   uint8_t i;
   for (i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
        can_rx.RX_CAN_DATA[i]=i*2;
        }
   
   
 // now call FIFO_AddItem and copy CAN Struct Data across to CAN FIFO Struct
                                        // *** call & test fifo_AddItem routine ***
                                        // 1) pass pointer to can_fifo
                                        // 2) pass pointer to can_Struct_fifo
                                        // 3) pass pointer to can_interrupt read data
                                        
                                        // fifo index will be at 0 as this is the first call
                                        
 ret = FIFO_AddItem( &can_fifo  , can_struct_fifo , &can_rx );
        
        
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
   
// *** call & test fifo_AddItem routine ***   
   
// lets write some more data in to the Can RX Strut, this will then get copied across to the Can Fifo Struct once FIFO_AddItem item is called
  
       
    can_rx.RX_CAN_Message_Type =60; 
    can_rx.RX_CAN_ID=70;
    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
    can_rx.RX_CAN_DATA[i]=i*3;
    }   
       
 
 // now call FIFO_AddItem and copy CAN Struct Data across to CAN FIFO Struct
                                        // *** call & test fifo_AddItem routine ***
                                        // 1) pass pointer to can_fifo
                                        // 2) pass pointer to can_Struct_fifo
                                        // 3) pass pointer to can_interrupt read data
                                        
                                        // fifo index will be at 1 as this is the first call
       
      ret = FIFO_AddItem( &can_fifo  , can_struct_fifo , &can_rx );  
   
   
   
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   
   
   
     b=1;        // select index of fifo to readback (fifo depth)

        printf ("\n\n\nLet's read back the CAN structure array data\n");
        printf("\n\n*****************************************");
        
        printf ("\nfifo depth[%d], CAN MESSAGE TYPE = %d",b, can_struct_fifo[b].RX_CAN_Message_Type);
        printf ("\nfifo depth[%d], CAN HEADDER ID= %d\n",b, can_struct_fifo[b].RX_CAN_ID);
                // loop round 8 times to read back CAN Data
        for (i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
        
        printf ("\nfifo depth[%d], CAN DATA byte[%d]= %d",b,i, can_struct_fifo[b].RX_CAN_DATA[i]);
        }
    
    
        printf("\n\nfifo above variables read back from fifo struct array");
        printf("\n*****************************************");
    return 0;
}


// ************************************************************************
// ****** FIFO INIT ROUTINE INITIALISES NEW STRUCTURE VALUES IN FIFO  *****
// ************************************************************************ 
                                                    // buffer init routine
                                                    // 1) pass struct fifo buffer pointer
                                                    // 2) pass size of can_rx structure  (one can packet)
                                                    // 3) pass size of can_fifo_stucture (declated # can packet fifo size)
void FIFO_Init(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, uint8_t can_struct_size,  uint16_t can_struct_fifo_size)
{
    // assert(0 != buff_state);
    buff_state->can_packet_size         = can_struct_size;      // store passed (can_struct_size) in fifo struct member (buff_state->can_packet_size)
    buff_state->can_packet_size_fifo    = can_struct_fifo_size; // store passed (can_struct_fifo_size) in fifo struct member (buff_state->can_packet_size_fifo)
    buff_state->head                    = 5;                    // store 0 in buff_state->head
    buff_state->tail                    = 6;                    // store 0 in buff_state->tail
    buff_state->count                   = 9;                    // store 0 in buff_state->count
                                                                // calculate fifo buffer depth from passed data
                                                                // store buffer depth in buff_state->fifo_depth_size  
    buff_state->fifo_depth_size         = buff_state->can_packet_size_fifo / buff_state->can_packet_size;
                                                                // print fifo truct member values just to confirm everything is correct.
    printf("\n\n*****************************************");
    printf("\ncan_struct_size       = %d",buff_state->can_packet_size);
    printf("\ncan_fifo_struct_size  = %d",buff_state->can_packet_size_fifo);
    printf("\ncan_fifo_depth        = %d",buff_state->fifo_depth_size);
    printf("\nfifo head             = %d",buff_state->head);
    printf("\nfifo tail             = %d",buff_state->tail);
    printf("\nfifo count            = %d",buff_state->count);
    printf("\n\nfifo above variables Initialised");
    printf("\n*****************************************");
}


// ************************************************************************
// ********* FIFO RESET ROUTINE RESETS & CLEARS DATA IN STRUCTURE *********
// ************************************************************************ 
                                                    // buffer reset routine
                                                    // 1) pass struct fifo buffer pointer to allow reset of fifo struct members

void FIFO_Reset(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{
    // assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    buff_state->head  = 0;                                  // store 0 in buff_state->head
    buff_state->tail  = 0;                                  // store 0 in buff_state->tail
    buff_state->count = 0;                                  // store 0 in buff_state->count
                                                            // print fifo truct member values just to confirm everything is correct.
    printf("\n\n*****************************************");                                                         
    printf("\nfifo head             = %d",buff_state->head);
    printf("\nfifo tail             = %d",buff_state->tail);
    printf("\nfifo count            = %d",buff_state->count);
    printf("\n\nfifo eliments above have been Reset");
    printf("\n*****************************************");
}


// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO IsEmpty ROUTINE RETURNS 1 FOR EMPTY & 0 FOR FULL********
// ************************************************************************ 
 
// return non-zero value if buffer is empty
                                                    // is fifo empty routine
                                                    // 1) pass struct fifo buffer pointer to allow read of fifo struct members

uint8_t FIFO_IsEmpty(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsEmpty = 0;                     // init fBufferIsEmpty to 0
                                                    // buffer has data condition (0) COUNT >0
 
    //assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    if (0 == buff_state->count)                     // IF 0 = count value (fifo member count)
    {
        fBufferIsEmpty = 1;                         // return 1 (buffer is empty)
    }
 
    return fBufferIsEmpty;                          // return variable fBufferIsEmpty
}



// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO RESET ROUTINE RESETS DATA IN STRUCTURE to 0   **********
// ************************************************************************ 
 
// return non-zero value if buffer is full
uint8_t FIFO_IsFull(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state)
{                                                   // is fifo full routine
                                                    // 1) pass struct fifo buffer pointer to allow read of fifo struct members
    uint8_t fBufferIsFull = 0;                      // set buffer not full
 
   // assert(0 != buff_state);
                                                    // if count is greater or equal to fifo_depth_size
    if (buff_state->count >= buff_state->fifo_depth_size)
    {
        fBufferIsFull = 1;                          // set buffer full flag
    }
 
    return fBufferIsFull;                           // return variable fBufferIsFull
}




// ************************************************************************
// ********** FIFO ADD ITEM ROUTINE Returns Non 0 If FIFO Full  ***********
// ************************************************************************ 

// return non-zero value if buffer is full
uint8_t  FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, can_pack_t * can_fifo, can_pack_t * const can_pac )
{
    uint8_t fBufferIsFull = 0;                  // set buffer full to 0
  uint8_t i=0;
  //  assert(0 != buff_state);
 
    fBufferIsFull = FIFO_IsFull(buff_state);    // call FIFO_IsFull Routine, returns 1 if full
 
    if (!fBufferIsFull)                         // if buffer not full proceed below
    {
        //buff_state->data[buff_state->head] = new_item;
        //buff_state->[buff_state->head] = new_item;
        
       can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_Message_Type = can_pac->RX_CAN_Message_Type;
       can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_ID           = can_pac->RX_CAN_ID;
       
       //for (i=0; i<8 ;i++)
    //    {
      // can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_DATA[i] = can_pac->RX_CAN_DATA[i];
    //    }
       
       memcpy (can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_DATA, can_pac->RX_CAN_DATA, 8 );
     
        printf("\n\n*****************************************"); 
     
        printf("\n\ncan write fifo[%d] Can Message Type Value   = %d",buff_state->head, can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_Message_Type);
        printf("\ncan write fifo[%d] Can Message Header Value = %d",buff_state->head, can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_ID);
        printf("\n");
 
  
        for (i=0; i<8 ;i++)
        {
        printf("\ncan write fifo[%d] Can Message Data Byte[%d]Value = %d",buff_state->head, i, can_fifo[buff_state->head].RX_CAN_DATA[i]);
        }
     
        printf("\n\nCAN Data eliments above have been written to FIFO");
        printf("\n*****************************************");
        
        buff_state->head++;             // increment fifo head
        buff_state->count++;            // increment fifo count
 
        if (buff_state->head >= buff_state->fifo_depth_size) // if head is greater or equal to fifo depth size then fifo FULL !!
        {
            buff_state->head = 0;                           // return 0 for fifo full
        }
  
 
    }
 
 
 
 
    return fBufferIsFull;
}
```

this is the output

```
size of can_rx   stucture = 16 bytes
size of can_fifo stucture = 160 bytes


*****************************************
can_struct_size       = 16
can_fifo_struct_size  = 160
can_fifo_depth        = 10
fifo head             = 5
fifo tail             = 6
fifo count            = 9

fifo above variables Initialised
*****************************************

*****************************************
fifo head             = 0
fifo tail             = 0
fifo count            = 0

fifo eliments above have been Reset
*****************************************

*****************************************
buffer has no data (empty) 1) 

Result from Function FIFI_IsEmpty
*****************************************

*****************************************
buffer is not full 0) 

Result from Function FIFI_IsFull
*****************************************

*****************************************

can write fifo[0] Can Message Type Value   = 6
can write fifo[0] Can Message Header Value = 7

can write fifo[0] Can Message Data Byte[0]Value = 0
can write fifo[0] Can Message Data Byte[1]Value = 2
can write fifo[0] Can Message Data Byte[2]Value = 4
can write fifo[0] Can Message Data Byte[3]Value = 6
can write fifo[0] Can Message Data Byte[4]Value = 8
can write fifo[0] Can Message Data Byte[5]Value = 10
can write fifo[0] Can Message Data Byte[6]Value = 12
can write fifo[0] Can Message Data Byte[7]Value = 14

CAN Data eliments above have been written to FIFO
*****************************************

*****************************************

can write fifo[1] Can Message Type Value   = 60
can write fifo[1] Can Message Header Value = 70

can write fifo[1] Can Message Data Byte[0]Value = 0
can write fifo[1] Can Message Data Byte[1]Value = 3
can write fifo[1] Can Message Data Byte[2]Value = 6
can write fifo[1] Can Message Data Byte[3]Value = 9
can write fifo[1] Can Message Data Byte[4]Value = 12
can write fifo[1] Can Message Data Byte[5]Value = 15
can write fifo[1] Can Message Data Byte[6]Value = 18
can write fifo[1] Can Message Data Byte[7]Value = 21

CAN Data eliments above have been written to FIFO
*****************************************


Let's read back the CAN structure array data


*****************************************
fifo depth[1], CAN MESSAGE TYPE = 60
fifo depth[1], CAN HEADDER ID= 70

fifo depth[1], CAN DATA byte[0]= 0
fifo depth[1], CAN DATA byte[1]= 3
fifo depth[1], CAN DATA byte[2]= 6
fifo depth[1], CAN DATA byte[3]= 9
fifo depth[1], CAN DATA byte[4]= 12
fifo depth[1], CAN DATA byte[5]= 15
fifo depth[1], CAN DATA byte[6]= 18
fifo depth[1], CAN DATA byte[7]= 21

fifo above variables read back from fifo struct array
*****************************************
```

now.... why could I not access the struc array when passing struct array like this

first I was sending the CAN struct array like this

```
uint8_t  FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, can_pack_t * const can_fifo, can_pack_t * const can_pac )
```

the way I got it to work was removing the const

```
uint8_t  FIFO_AddItem(fifo_buffer_t * const buff_state, can_pack_t * can_fifo, can_pack_t * const can_pac )
```

one way you ref the struct by

```
can_fifo->member (used with const)
```

and the other way with no const you ref

```
can_fifo.member (used with no const)
```

this way worked with the struct array when passing to function, yet the can_fifo->member did not

please can someone explain why ?

Thank you

Comment: Please do formatting proper..